# How can I match the domain part of a URL in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, preg-replace

I'm so bad at regexp, but I'm trying to get `some/path/image.jpg` out of `http://somepage.com/some/...etc` and trying this method:

```
function removeDomain($string) {

    return preg_replace("/http:\/\/.*\//", "", $string);

}
```

It isn't working -- so far as I can tell it's just returning a blank string. How do I write this regexp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use [`parse_url`](http://docs.php.net/parse_url)

Answer (score 2):

you might want to use this rather than regex:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
this will break up the URL for you, so you just read the resulting array for the domain name

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_url` as other people have already said.

But to answer your question about why your regex isn't working, it will match an *entire* URL because `.*` matches anything, and indeed it is. It is matching the *whole* URL, and replacing it with an empty string, hence your results. Try the following instead which will only match a hostname (anything up to the first '/'):

```
function removeDomain($string) {
    return preg_replace("@^https?://[^/]+/@", "", $string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While SilentGhost is right, the reason your regex is failing is because .* is greedy, and will eat everything, as long as there is a `/` afterwards.

If you put a `?` mark after your `.*`, it will only match until the first `/`

```
function removeDomain($string) {

    return preg_replace("/http:\/\/.*?\//", "", $string);

}
```